# IE renders unnecessary div elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2 and more than one of my xhtml pages render unwanted div content.
The same content is not rendered in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<div id="someid">
<div class="someclass">
.......
.......
</div>
</div>
```

This is the unwanted content.

Also I see the above code twice in the page source.

**Update:**

As you can see below the div content above h:form tag is observed twice in the page source

```
<ui:composition xmlns=.....>


<div id="modal" title="Message">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="strong">
            Message
        </p>

        <p class="top-margin">
            A message..........
        </p>

        <div class="button">
            <span class="cancel"> 
 <span class="submit"> <a href="#" class="close window">Cancel</a> </span> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <h:form id="formid" prependId="false" 
        class="formclass">
        <div class="columns">
    // Form content displayed as usual
            </h:form>
</div>
```

##

Comment: Can I see the JSF 2 code and any javascript you may have in the page.

Comment: perhaps you have some invalid HTML and IE is simply doing a worse job of guessing at what it should be than FF or Chrome

Comment: Maybe JSF has browser detection (through the User Agent) and decides to render different HTML depending on the browser calling the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
#someid, .someclass{
display:none;
}
```

That will not *render the unwanted content*.

Comment: But the content is not displayed wherever the id and class are used.

Comment: The content needs to be displayed only when it has to be. Firefox and Chrome are doing a good job.

Comment: I  can't do anything until I see some screenshots.. voting down isn't helpful either

Comment: Obviously I don't have the rep to vote down, someone else could have done that. I'll try to post some screenshots anyway.

Comment: Definitely post screenshots and I can try help you, I don't have IE because I'm on a Mac.